# Not able to input as c++ program exits

Tags: c++

So this a program to check how many times a string has the word chef.The program is compiling properly but when i run it shows that the process exited.
I am not able to input anything . How do i solve this? Here's my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


int chef_count(string s){
  int count=0,cur=0,c,h,e,f;
    while(cur!=(s.size()-2)){
      c=0,h=0,e=0,f=0;
      if(s[cur]=='c'||s[cur+1]=='c'||s[cur+2]=='c'||s[cur+3]=='c'){
        c++;
      }
      else if(s[cur]=='h'||s[cur+1]=='h'||s[cur+2]=='h'||s[cur+3]=='h'){
        h++;
      } 
      else if(s[cur]=='e'||s[cur+1]=='e'||s[cur+2]=='e'||s[cur+3]=='e'){
        e++;
      }
      else if(s[cur]=='f'||s[cur+1]=='f'||s[cur+2]=='f'||s[cur+3]=='f'){
        f++;
      }
      if(c==1 && e==1 && h==1 && f==1){
        count++;
      }
      cur++;
    }
  return count;

}


int main(){
  int n;
  int val;
  vector<string> store;
  string s;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    getline(cin,s);
    store.push_back(s);

  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    val=chef_count(store[i]);
    if (val>0){
      cout << val <<endl;
    }
    else{
      cout << "normal" <<endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: That's a really bad way to check. Why not use ``find``: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Uninitialized local variables are truly *uninitialized*. Their values will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random. And using them in any way without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You should always check the length of a `string` before using indices.  If the string is length 2, then s[2] will access out of bounds and be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

`for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` - you'll need a value for `n` there.

Your compiler should have warned you for that. Look for warnings about "uninitialized variable"

Answer (score 0):

Use if instead of else if. Set a value for n and do cur=cur+4 because you are already checking the first 4 letters of the string for the word 'chef'.
Below is a working version of your code: (your code checks for all permutations of the word 'chef' in the string):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int chef_count(string s){
  int count=0,cur=0,c,h,e,f;
    while(cur<(s.size())-1){
      c=0,h=0,e=0,f=0;
      if(s[cur]=='c'||s[cur+1]=='c'||s[cur+2]=='c'||s[cur+3]=='c'){
        c++;
      }
       if(s[cur]=='h'||s[cur+1]=='h'||s[cur+2]=='h'||s[cur+3]=='h'){
        h++;
      } 
       if(s[cur]=='e'||s[cur+1]=='e'||s[cur+2]=='e'||s[cur+3]=='e'){
        e++;
      }
       if(s[cur]=='f'||s[cur+1]=='f'||s[cur+2]=='f'||s[cur+3]=='f'){
        f++;
      }
      if(c==1 && e==1 && h==1 && f==1){
        count++;
      }
      cur=cur+4;
    }
  return count;

}


int main(){
  int n=2;
  int val;
  vector<string> store;
  string s;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      getline(cin,s);
    store.push_back(s);

  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    val=chef_count(store[i]);
    if (val>0){
      cout << val <<endl;
    }
    else{
      cout << "normal" <<endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it is checking for all combinations of the word chef in a string. If you are looking for the exact word then you should code that way.

Comment: yeah, the letters are mixed up. The input case is something like this : 
 ifehcfisgoodforchess - word chef occurs two times

Comment: In that case just count for the number of c's,h's,e's and f's. If the count is equal then print it else print the smallest count among that of c or h or e or f.